# Are there any services to tell black list address?

Tags: fraud, taint-analysis

I'd like to know the addresses used for a fraud, in order to make a service for analysing bitcoin blockchain. If you know the service for that, could you tell me it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No and active work is being done to make this even harder as we speak. [Fungibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fungibility) is a necessity of a currency, black lists are not compatible with that.